# How to move objects with different y positions by a certain number of units

Tags: unity

As seen in the image below, I have game objects with different y positions. I would like to select and change their y position by say, 2 units downwards while maintaining the gap. Please note I want this to be done through the inspector. I tried adding 2 units, but this just put all four objects on the same line. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group the game objects under a common parent, and then try adding 2 units to y of the parent game object.

Comment: If you're looking for an inspector only solution then this is definitely the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

An other solution would be to rely on the [snap settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PositioningGameObjects.html)  :

1. Hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd> on Mac)
2. Click on the gameobjects in the hierarchy (or the scene view)
3. Keep <kbd>CTRL</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd> on Mac) pressed and move the green axis vertically
4. The objects should snap on the grid and move 1 unit at a time

You can change the Snap settings in the `Edit > Snap Settings...` menu.

[image: Snap settings]
<sub>(source: [unity3d.com](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/SceneViewUnitSnappingSettings.png))</sub>